# Catch all OPTIONS requests with RESTEasy

Tags: java, resteasy

I can catch all OPTIONS requests like this:

```
@Provider
public class OptionsException implements
        ExceptionMapper<DefaultOptionsMethodException> {

    @Context HttpServletRequest req; // as suggested by @Ivan

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(DefaultOptionsMethodException ex) {
        String u = req.getRequestURI();
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

}
```

But, can I know the request (URI) that produces the exception ?

Comment: What about adding `@Context HttpServletRequest request`?

Comment: Ok, got this. Thank you.